# Huge memory footprint for simple select statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory

I have a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T](
[FileID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Line] [nvarchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

FileID is a foreign key, and the table has > 7,000,000 records

Doing a select count(1) on this table causes a memory spike of 1.5GB+. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Do you have any indices on the table? If not: they only way SQL Server can count the rows is by scanning the whole table. Put an index on `FileID` and I'm sure your memory usage will be far less (since now, SQL Server can scan that index of 8 bytes per entry to determine the number of rows)

Comment: Adding an index made the situation much better; it now goes up 0.4 GB now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to block all your users while you're getting a count, and can accept minor differences due to transactions currently occurring, then this is much better:

```
SELECT SUM([rows]) FROM sys.partitions
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T')
  AND index_id IN (0,1);
```

Otherwise Marc is right - put an index on the `FileID` column and SQL Server will choose to scan that index instead of scanning the entire table.

Is there really no index on this table? There are a few use cases where no clustered index makes sense, but I don't suspect this is one of them. While creating a foreign key can help the optimizer, it does not create an index (though that is a common misconception).